# How to set mm with multiple fields in Solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene, search-engine, solrj

In the schema.xml, I have 3 fields - id, text and type. I set default operator to "AND"

My query is "q = (text:fire at Thai square) (type:fire)"

I tried to use edismax and set mm to 75% but It doesn't work with multiple fields.

Comment: what's your problem with minShouldMatch. Also, do you really have brackets in query you use? How your qf param looks like?

Comment: There is a good chance that you got your brackets wrong. In case you want all these words (fire at Thai square) to be queried against the field text, then your brackets are placed wrong ...

Comment: query.setQuery(queryString);
query.setParam("fl", "* score");
query.setParam("defType", "edismax");
query.setParam("mm", "75%");
query string is as same as q in my Question